# Best practices in ncurses: using stdscr or only created windows?

Tags: user-interface, ncurses

I hope my title is clear enough.
To be more specific: let's say i want to make ncurses app which will have more than one window.
Here is my problem:
What is better practice in general: using stdscr + N-1 manually created windows (assuming i will be using N windows), or just working with N manually created windows and abandon usage of stdscr at all (except for the fact that it will still be there) ?

It may not be very serious issue, but im wondering and i'd gladly read some opinions from ncurses-experienced devs.
Thanks in advance.

PS.
I believe that programming language/environment doesn't really matter here, but just in case i'll say it may be C/C++ on Linux

Answer (score 2):

This question can only be answered with an opinion, not objectively. That said -- I would avoid using stdscr. For one thing, stdscr is always going to match the screen size, while your other windows will (presumably) be sized to fit their purposes. So stdscr is going to overlap with each of the other windows, meaning you'd have to be careful in what order you updated the windows.

Comment: that is the intuition i had, nice to know there are people with the same opinion

Comment: Consider using the panels library to handle overlapping and stacked windows.